# How to rename directory in Windows Command Prompt using pattern?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have some directories with names in format:

```
companyName_a13d0116cc
```

(`unique name` + `underscore` + `random string`)

Is it possible to rename all directories using just CMD like this?

```
companyName_a13d0116cc -> companyName
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: How are you using the `REN` command? Use the command `REN /?` to see documentation.

Comment: In an open command window enter this as a single line `for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b /AD "X:\path\*_*" ') do for /f "delims=_" %B in (%A) do ren "%%~fA" "%B"` change `X:\path` to fit your environment. In a batch file double all `%` to `%%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with the following way:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /B /AD "*_*"') do (
    for /F "delims=_" %%B IN ("%%A") do ren "%%~fA" "%%B"
)
```

For cmd one-line use:

```bat
for /F "delims=" %A IN ('dir /B /AD "*_*"') do for /F "delims=_" %B IN ("%A") do ren "%~fA" "%B"
```